# Gemfile git branch for Beanstalk unable to bundle install

Tags: ruby, git, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my Gemfile I have

```
gem 'slim', :git => 'git://github.com/brennancheung/slim.git', :branch => 'angularjs_support'
```

which is a branch of the slim gem required for me to run AngularJS correctly with my views. I've pushed my code to my beanstalk application but am unable to bundle install according to the logs shown below...

```
sh: git: command not found
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/brennancheung/slim.git'
"/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/slim-700ed452e752ccb6baf9de9d0a46fbded8bb2da5"
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.
```

I'm new to Beanstalk and have no idea how to fix this. Any help on how to get bundle to install successfully would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make sure git is installed http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Hmm if that's the case, I have no idea how to install git on the Beanstalk machine.

Comment: I didn't realize you were on an amazon instance. Go ahead and ssh into the eb instance and run the command `which git` and post the output here

Comment: It is unlikely that EB instance will have git installed. I know mine doesn't :) I see three alternatives: install `git` with config file, get the files from `slim` repo into your project prior to deployment, or get files directly from github with http.

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to look into how I can do that with a config file. I was running with the idea of sshing into the machine.

Comment: well, when you ssh to the machine, I can tell you the output: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-76 ~]$ which git
/usr/bin/which: no git in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

Comment: Ah, one more alternative. Clone `slim` and copy it to S3, then on container start-up copy the contents to your instance. I personally like this one.

Comment: Container commands for config: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands

Comment: Awesome thanks. I won't try this out till later tonight but when I do I'll make sure to update details. I would go ahead and publish this as an answer and if it works I'll give credit.

Comment: @jason328: Which of the options did you pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `git` is not installed on by default on EC2 instance, you would have to find a workaround solution:

a. Install git on instance with configuration file and command.
*It is the most obvious way to solve the problem, although not be the most efficient.*

b. Clone `slim` repository into your project, so it will be deployed together.
*Seems that `slim` is not being actively developed lately, so having the copy in your project might   not be a bad idea. It protects you from `github.com` being down, yet you will have extra files to carry around.*

c. Use configuration file and commands to pull the data from github.com directly with http.
*Too many files to work with, and also dependency on third party service.*

d. Use a combination of above. Clone `slim` repository and copy files to S3. Use configuration and commands to copy files from S3 to your instance.
*It seems like the most elegant and efficient way to solve the problem.*

It might look something like:

```
$ cat .ebextensions/myapp.config

commands:
    10-copy-slim-from-s3
        command: "aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/slim slim --recursive"
```

Comment: I went ahead with option A.